# CDF of a random variable with different distributions in different range

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function

I have a random variable $X$ that follows an exponential distribution $\exp(1)$ in the range $(0, t)$ ($t$ is a fixed point), but follows another exponential distribution $\exp(2)$ in the range $(t, \infty)$. How can I get the cumulative distribution function of $X$?

Comment: Can you clarify the pdf a bit more?

Comment: the pdf is $f(x) = \exp(-x)$ betweem $(0,t)$ and $f(x) = 2\exp(-2x)$ betweem $(t,\infty)$

Comment: Are you sure than the area under the PDF is equal to 1? If I get it correctly, the area under the first part is $ 1-exp(-t)$ and under the second part is $ exp(-2t)$; these two do not sum to 1.

Comment: Right, that's the problem. I am trying to imagine a situation like this: say I am waiting a bus, the wait time follows exp(1) first, but suddenly it starts to rain, the rate of the exponential distribution becomes 2 now. Then what's the distribution of the wait time?

Comment: So, your problem is not just the CDF, but rather how to define your distribution (PDF/CDF) according to the situation you're describing. Please edit this description of the problem into your question, it will help clarifying what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try answering according to the problem description you gave in the comments.

Say that you're waiting for an event to happen, and that event has a PDF $ f_1(x) = exp(-x) $ if $ 0<=x<=t_0 $, but if you've waited until $ t_0$, the PDF changes into $ f_2(x) = 2 \cdot exp(-2x) $.

You can say that the time ($x$) in the second part is not the time since you began waiting for the event, but the time since you entered that second stage, i.e. $t_0$ : this changes $f_2(x)$ to $ 2 \cdot exp (-2(x-t_0)) $.

Additionally, you know that the probability to reach that second stage is $ exp(-t_0) $ to begin with, so the total probability for the event to happen at any time in the second stage must be multiplied by this factor (or, put otherwise, must sum to this) - giving $ f_2(x) = exp(-t_0) \cdot 2 \cdot exp(-2(x-t_0)) $

To sum it up, you can define the PDF $ f_1(x) = exp(-x) $ if $0<=x<=t_0 $ and $ f_2(x) = exp(-t_0) \cdot 2exp(-2(x-t_0)) $ if $ x>t_0$.

From here, it's relatively easy to calculate the CDF:
$ F(x) =  1-exp(-x) $ if $ 0<=x<=t_0 $ and $ F(x) =  1-exp(-2x+t_0) $ if $ 0<=x<=t_0 $

Comment: Thank you so much! That solves the problem.

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer answer your questions, please mark it as "accepted" (with the little "v" mark).